# Thunderbolt 27" resolution

Tags: resolution, thunderbolt-display

I have a mid-2012 Macbook Pro with Retina. I love it, but I needed more screen real-estate for my current work, so I got a 27" Thunderbolt display. It's very big, and I have lots of room now, but I do have a problem. If I use the native resolution (2560 X 1440), I find text everywhere to be slightly too small. If I try the next "step" in the Display options (2048 X 1152), the text is bigger alright, but of course, it gets too blurry. Is there some way of doing an "in-between" step, between the native and the 2nd step? Or are there other ways of slightly enlarging the text? I guess I could "zoom" in Chrome, for example. Any other similar suggestions for other programs?

Comment: This is a hard to answer question as the ability to zoom text is dependent on the application you're using. In Finder for example you can hit `cmd+j` to open the view preferences and change the text font size. Other programs like Photoshop also enable you to change the GUI font size. I'm not aware of a method to change to an "in-between" resolution though.

Comment: Thanks all. I think I'm going to stick with native and do per-app zooming when necessary; I'm already starting to get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The display is crispest at it's native resolution of 2560 X 1440. I would suggest adjusting the text size in each app. This is a bit of a pain because it seems that some apps render the same font/size combo differently. Most apps seem to have font/size adjustments with some, like Mail.app, having adjustments for each of the major control areas (mailboxes, summary, mail display).

There are third party apps like [SwitchRes](http://www.madrau.com/indexSRX4.html) that may show you intermediate steps. When I run a monitor at a non-native resolution I get a headache in about 5 minutes. The only exception to this is on my Macbook Pro Retina running the "More Space" (1920X1200) setting in the Display preference panel.[image: Display Prefs]

Answer (score 1):

Well, in most applications you can just hit CMD-equalsign or CMD-plussign to increase the font size.
It is not an optimal solution, but it's what I'm doing all the time.